# IIS 5 Content type - Error

Tags: asp.net, permissions, powerpoint, content-type, iis-5

IIS5, Windows 2000. ASP.Net 1.1
Virtual Directory, NTFS, Read Permissions, under the web-directory there is sub-directory that contains PPT and DOC files. The asp.net code sends these PPT and DOC files to User (with IE6 and 8). (All Content-Types are properly configured in IIS by default) There is another service on a separate machines, basically which publishes these PPT and DOC files to the same directory but using the Windows File Sharing. There is rare chance that the PPT file is opened and the publication service is publishing the very same; though even if it is opened, it will be opened only by IIS throwing it to client, so a read-only version has been sent to the client. Additionally the same directly with published PPT and DOC files is made as READONLY for all from NTFS permissions and Full Permission access for the Publication Service credentials.

All works usually well until something **unknown** happens and IIS 5, though it sends the PPT file to the client but sends the content-type as text\xml so browsers like IE6 and Chrome unable to render PPT (binary) file as XML and shows XML character error, while IE 8 irrespective of what web-server is sending as content-type analyses File by itself (somehow) and understands that it is a PPT file and not XML and renders it via MS PowerPoint installed on the machine (in the MS PowerPoint window not IE window – ms office 2010).

Why IIS is behaving like that? What is (or can be) root cause? How to fix it?

Comment: It is not possible to install or update the web-server. I need to find and fix the cause here.
It is not even possible to replicate or simulate the issue, but right now it is occurring to one of the PPT files out of 500 published ones, which is basically reported as a fault.

Comment: Also noted IIS sending HTTP 100 - Continue intermittently.. (may be this is not related)

Mime-Types are all fine defined as default in IIS 5, verified.
All publised PPTs are working fine, (received by client) except the error (reported) one.
Reponse headers are not being setup\altered by code but code is just throwing the file, ppt. IIS sets header\content-type itself, only by mistake on this reported PPT file set it as xml, otherwise for all ppt it sends proper type, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint like that..

Comment: Interesting:
I rename the same reported ppt file, and modify config so that asp.net code now throw me newly renamed ppt file (with same binary contents) from the front-end, it works fine (PPT mime type not xml), and then given same old name and then client gets same error, because of xml mime-type (error as invalid character found in xml).
Problem with (keeping same ppt) file name persists even after restarted the IIS server.Unfortunately restarting windows 2000 server is not possible.

Comment: This issue is happening with IIS6 with windows 2003 server as well. Restarting Server also does not solve the issue. I have checked NTFS permissions are same and inherited permissions are also same for both files - as far as windows file properties dialog-box can tell me. -- Refer here for more: http://forums.iis.net/p/1174289/1965798.aspx